# NTFS compression error on server 2016 with /EXE

Tags: ntfs, windows-server-2016

I'm trying to transparently compress some files using the `compact` utility on my file server. These files are basically text backups, and compress easily at 10:1 or higher.

They are rarely read and never written to, so I'd like to use the better-optimized `XPRESS4K` or `LZX` compression for this purpose. However, I'm getting the following error:

```
compact /c /exe:XPRESS4K .\BigFile.dat

 Compressing files in D:\Exports\

BigFile.dat [ERR]
BigFile.dat: The file system does not support compression.
```

However, it works normally in other ways:

- a normal `compact /c D:\Exports\BigFile.dat` completes successfully (but is extremely slow).
- I can also copy the same file to the `C:` drive, and then using `/exe:XPRESS4k` works normally.

I've checked that the cluster sizes are correct, though I don't think they're required any more:

- `chkdsk D: /I /C` returns `4096 bytes in each allocation unit`,

  - and `The type of the file system is NTFS`, which is supported.
- The OS is windows server 2016 and up to date.
- `fsutil fsinfo ntfsinfo O:` returns the same versions and cluster/sector size as for `C:`

I understand something is wrong with the file system, but there shouldn't be any other requirements as far as I can tell?

Comment: I suppose there may be a reason you are not using PS on your server but just in case, wanted to share two method that do something similar on Server 2016 that worked for me, just in case: https://pastebin.com/Qtgz5Peh. I have not tried to optimize or figure out ways to make method 1 "fastest" but that may be possible too. FYI at a minimum otherwise (even if you already know I guess).

Answer (score 1):

Please note that `compact.exe` supports two different methods:

1. The classic NTFS compression that is present also in old versions of Windows, and can be enabled/disabled from File Explorer with the "Compress contents to save disk space". This is the compression used when no /EXE parameter is set.
2. Windows Overlay Filter (Wof) or DeviceIOControl with control code FSCTL_SET_EXTERNAL_BACKING. The one that is used with `/EXE:*algorithm*`

When you use the Wof compression in the C: volume in a Windows 2016 it works, however in an attached data volume it may fail with "The file system does not support compression.". I don't know the reason or if it's a bug, but Windows 2016 is fully compatible with LZX and XPRESS algorithms as it is able to read and write the related alternate data stream `Wof­Compressed­Data` in the system root volume.

As a workaround you can follow these steps to be able to use compact.exe with Wof in a data volume in a Windows 2016:

1. Attach the data volume to a Windows 10/11 system.
2. Compact any file in the attached data volume with the /EXE parameter.
3. Detach the data volume and attach it to the Windows 2016 system

From this point you'll be able to compact any file or folder in the data volume even from any Windows 2016.